# How can I filter tags with django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm doing the following to filter the posts by tag. But the problem is when clicking the tag button,  I do not see any results. The following code represents the urls.py, model.py, view.py, challengePage.html, tag.html

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns =[
......
    path('challengePage/', views.ChallengePage, name ='challengePage'),
   path('tag/<str:tag>/', views.tag, name='tag_argument'),   
]
```

The model.py :

```
    class Challenge_code(models.Model): #create a table
    auther = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    body =RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
   
    image = models.ImageField(null = True,blank=True ,upload_to='attach/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

the views.py :

```
def ChallengePage(request):
    challenges = Challenge_code.objects.prefetch_related('tags').all().order_by('-created_at')
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {
        'challenges' : challenges,
        'tags':tags,
    }
    return render(request,'challengePage.html',context)

def tag(request,tag):
    challenges_tag = Challenge_code.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)
    return render(request, 'tag.html',{'tag':tag, 'challenges':challenges_tag})
```

the challengePage.html :

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    {% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="{% url 'tag_argument' tag %}"><button style="text-align: center;"  dir="ltr" class="buttonTag buttonTag2"
    >   {{tag.name}}</button></a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

the tag.html :

```
<div class="code_body">
    <div class="container_code">
          {% for challenge in challenges_tag %}
        <div class="Box_code">  
            <p class="title_code"><bdi style="  color: #000;">
              {{challenge.title}}
              <br>
              {% for tag in challenge.tags.all %}
                <small>{{tag}}, </small>
                {% endfor %}
            </bdi>
            </p>
            <a href="{% url 'challenge' challenge.id %}"><button class="button1" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Join</span></button></a>
            <p class="name-user">
              <bdi>
              By: 
               {{challenge.auther.username}} 
              </bdi>
            </p>
        </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please provide model code

Comment: Challenge_code Model have tags field is ManytoMany  ??

Comment: class Challenge_code(models.Model):
        tags = TaggableManager()

Comment: Please update full code of model in question

Comment: Edit question and put there model code

Comment: answer is updated please check it

Answer (score 0):

i am using it on my current project
i urls.py use

```
tag/<slug:tag_slug>
```

in views.py

```
tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
query = your_model.filter(tags__in=[tag])
```

do not forget to import this in your views.py

```
from taggit.models import Tag
```

it works very fine with me change it to be suitable for your purpose and i am ready to help but first follow this